# Display error message when aborting input (ctrl-c) with DOS interrupt 0Ah (read input to buffer)

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

I prompt the user for input:

```
mov ah, 0Ah
mov dx, OFFSET buffer
int 21h
```

My assignment tells me that control-c should "abort the program with an appropriate error message". How is this done?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always consult Ralf Brown's Interrupt list for 16-bit programming.

[**Int 21/AH=0Ah** (BUFFERED INPUT)](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm) says:

> **Notes:** ^C/^Break are checked, and INT 23 is called if either detected.

[**Int 23h** (CONTROL-C/CONTROL-BREAK HANDLER)](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-4110.htm) says:

> Any DOS call may safely be made within the INT 23 handler, although the handler must check for a recursive invocation if it does call DOS.

Use [**Int 21/AH=25h** (SET INTERRUPT VECTOR)](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2602.htm) to register your own interrupt handler, where you print the message and exit.

Related:

- [Why can't I hook INT 23 in DOS?](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/alt.msdos.programmer/8hZLdZwJNhQ/discussion)

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me how 25h is implemented. May I ask for an example?

Comment: I've never used it before personally, but I believe all you have to do is `mov dx, OFFSET my_handler;  mov ax, 2523h; int 21h;` - There's a brief snippet in that article.